# Holiday project goals for undergrads with an FPGA?

Tags: computer-vision, vhdl, fpga, xilinx, edge-detection

It's a student project for vacation research, under-grad, not sure how many of us, there'll probably be 4-6, we're motivated.

My original proposal was to get an FPGA (on an Artix-7 or Z-board) to run a CID camera sensor as a dumb peripheral, do some basic image processing stuff on it (perhaps edge detection and dynamic windowing), and output a bitmap to a PC.

One of the faculty who has about 16 years experience with FPGAs has suggested that for my (and my colleagues) level, this might not be achieveable in a 6-10 week time-frame (we're all pretty much beginners).

We wish to keep the original goal on a more long term basis, but want now to have some other project goals, that would move us towards having the skills and experience (and perhaps some of the IP) for this ultimate goal.

What would some good intermediate project goals be for a group of undergrad beginners with a summer holiday to spend if we ultimately would like to get an FPGA doing cool stuff with a CID camera sensor?

Comment: This question is not on topic at StackOverflow as defined by the scope in the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic/)**

Answer (score 2):

what about distance estimation - using two cameras or more in stereo.